# Tesseract OCR failed to identify some characters

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I'm working on a c++ project where I need to OCR some text fields. I'm using  Tesseract version 3.02 c++ API functions to achieve this. But the OCR results differ from the image.

The following image reads as "31 SW19 SQU" when i use api.GetUTF8Text() function.
[image: "31 SW19 SQU"]

and the following image as "31 SW19 3OU".
[image: "31 SW19 3OU"]

One problem is tesseract identifies the first character as "3" and fails to identify it within "3QU" correctly.

Can someone explain to me why the tesseract fails to identify these images or any guidance to fix the issue.

Comment: Have you set the psm value to other than the default? If so, what value?

Comment: PSM contains the default value. I haven't change it

Answer (score 0):

I screen grabbed that image and ran it through my setup (v5.0.0 alpha) and it got it right for me:

```
def TestImage2String(file):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    gray, th = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    out = pytesseract.image_to_string(th)
    print(out)
```

The output was:

```
SW19 3QU
```

It's Python, but the c++ API is very similar.